# Check if Date is in the past & if a cell is blank

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I am trying get excel to show the word `"Error"` if the date in cell `M2` is in the past AND if column `L2` is blank however this is not working, any help is much appreciated!

It would be even better if I could get it to see if the date IS today or before today, rather than just before today

```
=IF(AND(M2<TODAY(),L2=""),"ERROR","OK")
```

Comment: Instead of `M2<TODAY()`, just use `M2<=TODAY()` to include today in your check. Regarding _"however this is not working"_ - can you elaborate? What isn't working about it as it looks fine? Have you checked that the formatting type for column `M:M` is a datetime and not text?

Comment: Turns out that in column L2 there was a "space" which was throwing the formula off, I have amended as per what you have said and it works now! thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've replaced commas with semi-colons in Google Sheet and it works:

```
=IF(AND(M2<=TODAY();L2="");"ERROR";"OK")
```

Check your regional settings, as user @SJR pointed out.

Comment: Why do you think using semi-colons instead of commas will make the formula work?

Comment: @SJR, since I do not have Excel installed in my machine, I've tried using Google Sheet and it uses semi-colons. When I try with commas an error appears and I thought it was the same issue.

Comment: That's a regional setting. Some countries use commas, some use semi-colons.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was a regional setting.

Comment: I'll insert a note in my answer to clarify my point.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
=IF(AND(M2<=TODAY(),ISBLANK(L2)),"ERROR","OK")
```